# Numerical precision of LU decomposition with complex64

Tags: numpy, precision

I'm looking for the most accurate C-like implementation for solving system of linear equations of complex **floats** type (aka `np.complex64`). Was going for LU decomposition. I wanted to first implement it in numpy, see that it all goes well and then translate the implementation to C.

This is what I currently got:

```
import scipy.linalg as la
import numpy as np


def lu_factor(A):
    L, U = np.empty_like(A), np.empty_like(A)
    n = A.shape[0]
    for k in range(n):
        L[k, k] = 1
        U[k, k] = A[k, k] - L[k, :k] @ U[:k, k]
        for j in range(k + 1, n):
            U[k, j] = A[k, j] - L[k, :k] @ U[:k, j]
        for i in range(k + 1, n):
            L[i, k] = (A[i, k] - L[i, :k] @ U[:k, k]) / U[k, k]
    return L, U


def forward_sub(L, b):
    x = np.empty_like(b)
    for i in range(b.size):
        x[i] = (b[i] - L[i, :i] @ x[:i]) / L[i, i]
    return x


def backward_sub(U, b):
    x = np.empty_like(b)
    for i in reversed(range(b.size)):
        x[i] = (b[i] - U[i, i + 1:] @ x[i + 1:]) / U[i, i]
    return x


def lu_solve(A, b):
    L, U = lu_factor(A)
    return backward_sub(U, forward_sub(L, b))


b = np.array([6 + 1j, -4 + 2j, 27 + 3j], dtype=np.complex128)
A = np.array([
    [1 + 4j, 1 + 5j,  1 + 6j],
    [0 + 7j, 2 + 8j,  5 + 9j],
    [2 + 1j, 5 + 2j, -1 + 3j],
], dtype=np.complex128)


x_expected = la.lu_solve(la.lu_factor(A), b)
x = lu_solve(A, b)
np.testing.assert_allclose(x_expected, x)
```

`A` & `b` were randomly chosen. Note - their type is `np.complex128` (complex doubles) and the result of the "naive" implementation is close enough to the scipy one.

When changing the types to `np.complex64` (complex floats) we get:

```
Mismatch: 66.7%
Max absolute difference: 1.0612305e-06
Max relative difference: 6.8692873e-07
x: array([ 1.387071-0.680237j,  3.673277+1.09019j , -3.683192-1.225474j], dtype=complex64)
y: array([ 1.387072-0.680236j,  3.673277+1.090189j, -3.683192-1.225474j], dtype=complex64)
```

`e-06` seems pretty high to me. Is there are good explanation besides the "double to float accuracy"? What exactly numpy /BLAS do that I don't? Can this be replicate using basic operations?

NOTE: performance is non-issue for me, I only care about precision.

Comment: e-06 is pretty close to resolution of float32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coding a robust and accurate numerical linear algebra procedure can be very tricky.
My first suggestion would be to use a mature library like [Lapack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAPACK)

If you want to code your own LU it is absolutely mandatory to use at least ["partial pivoting"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition) to have a robust procedure, otherwise:

> Without a proper ordering or permutations in the matrix, the
>   factorization may fail to materialize.

*Note:* wikepedia suggest an implementation that can certainly be a good starting point. You will just have to modify it to support complex numbers instead of doubles.

Once that you have solved your system one can improve precision by performing one or two steps of [iterative refinement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_refinement)

```
Compute the residual: r = b − A.x
Solve the system:     A.d = r
Add the correction:   x = x + d
```

Just apply the previous procedure using your LU code to solve the A.d=r system. If you are looking for high precision, do not neglect this last step, it generally works very well in practice.